# Entity Framework 6 select by foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My classes

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int userId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number Required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Service> services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int serviceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Service Name Required.")]
    public string serviceName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Service Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Service Type")]
    public int serviceType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Service Price")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Service Price")]
    public int servicePrice { get; set; }
}
```

The two above classes are my model in code first approach. I am trying to query all services belonging to specific user.

Can anyone help me with this please?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 'services' property as virtual in User class.